# can't pipe on observable not working using ngrx

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx

I get data from ngrx using a selector

```
  schedules$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsTimes));
```

Then in Oninit I pipe on the observable

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new GetSelectedItem());
  this.store.dispatch(new GetSchedules());
  let data = this.schedules$.pipe(
    map((elm: ISchedule[]) => {
      return elm.map((elm: ISchedule) => {
        return { tp_org_r: elm.tp_org_r, tp_des_r: elm.tp_des_r };
      });
    })
  );
```

}

I get never enter inside the `map` I don't know why ?

Comment: you need to subscribe to `data` somewhere, otherwise the observable has no way to know that it should emit. For that matter, you might also want to subscribe to `data` *before* your `dispatch` calls, otherwise you won't be able to read the result of those actions from `schedules$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `let data` is a cold observable and won't trigger until you call the method subscribe.
check more on [Hot vs Cold Observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

```
data.subscribe(console.log)
```

> When does an Observable begin emitting its sequence of items? It depends on the Observable. A “hot” Observable may begin emitting items as soon as it is created, and so any observer who later subscribes to that Observable may start observing the sequence somewhere in the middle. A “cold” Observable, on the other hand, waits until an observer subscribes to it before it begins to emit items, and so such an observer is guaranteed to see the whole sequence from the beginning.
>
> In some implementations of ReactiveX, there is also something called a “Connectable” Observable. Such an Observable does not begin emitting items until its Connect method is called, whether or not any observers have subscribed to it.

Comment: thanks for your first contribute. so why pipe is working when with api calls?

if I use subscribe I'll not be able to use `async` pipe in html file